# How define lambda function in serverless with inlineCode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Consider a piece of serverless code:

```
functions:
  MyFunc:
    handler: index.handler
    name: "my_name"
    runtime: nodejs12.x
    memorySize: 512
    timeout: 30
    inlineCode: |
      exports.handler = function(event, context) {
          console.log("ok");
      };
    description: description
```

This leads to pacakge everything in source folder. I can not disable it. Event if I add:

```
package:
  artifact: dummy.zip
```

Deploy failed because `dummy.zip` is empty file. But why I need a zip file when specified `inlineCode`? Is there a way to disable packaging and deploy nodejs function with `inlineCode` parameter only?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of an `inlineCode` parameter is supported by `AWS::Serverless::Function`, but not `serverless-framework`. The YAML you pasted is not a 1:1 mapping to the `AWS::Serverless::Function`, it's specific to sls itself.

Store your code in files/directories until the sls team adds support for `inlineCode`. I didn't see any feature requests for it. I'm sure they'd be glad to get one from you.

Comment: ` I'm sure they'd be glad to get one from you.` - If I have a time... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to define lambda function deginition as normal cloudformation resource like that:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    MyFunc:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
      Properties:
        FunctionName: "my_name"
        Handler: index.handler
        Runtime: nodejs10.x
        Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn # do not forget to define role by hand :(
        Code:
          ZipFile: |
            exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
            console.log(event);
                const response = {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: JSON.stringify('Hello Node')
                };
                callback(null, response);
            };
```